# How to remove the two last characters of a column in a TSV file using awk, perl or sed?

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed

I would like to go from file A to file B using `awk` , `sed` or `perl` :

File A (tab separated) :

```
target_id       length  eff_length      est_counts      tpm
ENSORLT00000000001.1    1614    1663.8  266     2.69411
ENSORLT00000000002.8    1641    1724.36 62.1756 0.607613
ENSORLT00000000003.1    1389    1363.82 68.8244 0.850394
ENSORLT00000000004.3    537     484.396 2       0.0695767
ENSORLT00000000005.2    520     374.865 0       0
ENSORLT00000000007.1    1809    2083.96 699     5.65227
ENSORLT00000000008.4    1098    1099.36 423.548 6.49226
```

File B (tab separated) :

```
target_id       length  eff_length      est_counts      tpm
ENSORLT00000000001      1614    1663.8  266     2.69411
ENSORLT00000000002      1641    1724.36 62.1756 0.607613
ENSORLT00000000003      1389    1363.82 68.8244 0.850394
ENSORLT00000000004      537     484.396 2       0.0695767
ENSORLT00000000005      520     374.865 0       0
ENSORLT00000000007      1809    2083.96 699     5.65227
ENSORLT00000000008      1098    1099.36 423.548 6.49226
```

Each id in the first column has the same number of characters (except the column header).

I tried with `sed 's/ENSORLT*.*\..\t/ENSORLT*/g' FileA > FileB` but I think there is a problem with the `*`.

Comment: Why does this have Perl and sed tags if you want an awk solution?

Comment: Sorry, I changed the question, I wanted awk perl or sed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed 's/\..//' file
```

................

Answer (score 0):

using Perl Pie:

```
perl -pi -e 's/\..//' file
```

... for competeness ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR>1{sub(/..$/,"",$1)}1' OFS="\t" file

target_id       length  eff_length      est_counts      tpm
ENSORLT00000000001  1614    1663.8  266 2.69411
ENSORLT00000000002  1641    1724.36 62.1756 0.607613
ENSORLT00000000003  1389    1363.82 68.8244 0.850394
ENSORLT00000000004  537 484.396 2   0.0695767
ENSORLT00000000005  520 374.865 0   0
ENSORLT00000000007  1809    2083.96 699 5.65227
ENSORLT00000000008  1098    1099.36 423.548 6.49226
```